# Counting folders and executables when checking for executables only in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

My code is:

```bsh
function CountEx()
{

    echo "The number of executable files in this dir is: $count"
}
while
```

I am using it Like this:

```
 yaser.sh -x ./folder
```

The Output is `The number of files + folders`.

Comment: Am I getting you right that you want to find executables in a directory using shell script only? Why won't you want to use `find`?

Comment: In `bash`, there are several ways to increment a value without using the external program `expr`; the most succinct is `(( count+=1 ))`. Most similar to your existing code is `count=$((count + 1))`.

Answer (score 3):

The executable bit on folders has special meaning and is most often set. Try to filter for regular files with executable bit:

```
if [[ -f "$file" -a -x "$file" ]];
```

Of course, the whole exercise might be simplified by `find`:

```
find $folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -ls | wc -l
```

Comment: I don't think all versions of `find` have the `-executable` flag. You could use `-perm +111` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

May be all the files in your directory are set to executable permission. If you want to check only for elf files then use file command and grep for elf.

```
 file $file | grep elf > /dev/null
 if [ $? -eq. 0 ] ; then
     count = `expr $count +  1`
 fi
```